# Adding one to each element in an array using an enhanced for loop in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, int

hey guys i'm having some trouble working this out. The aim is to convert an int array like this `{1, 2, 3, 4}` by adding one to each element and printing it using an ENHANCED for loop, so it will look like this `{2, 3, 4, 5}`. This is what i got so far :

```
    int myArr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for (int i: myArr){
        i =+1;
        myWindow.writeOutLine(i);
    }
```

Pretty sure that is not close, i'm unsure how to store the new value in the array and go to next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use separate index variable if you have to use enhanced loop.

```
int myArr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int count = 0 ;
for (int i: myArr){
     myArr[count] = i+1;
     myWindow.writeOutLine(myArr[count]);
     count++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with the enhanced for loop, since that loop hides the indices of the array, so you can't modify the array.

Use a traditional for loop instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    myArr[i]++;
    myWindow.writeOutLine(myArr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Well, technically he *could* use the for each loop *if* he uses his own index variable in addition, but that would pretty much defeat the purpose of the for each.

Comment: @domdom That's true.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] myArr = {1, 2, 3, 4};

    for(int i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
        int x = 1; // Amount to increment each value by
        myArr[i] = myArr[i] + x;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArr));
```