# Add result to int array every time you finish counting the occurrence

Tags: java, arrays, oop, counter

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create array with days of week. won't be modified
        String[] daysOfWeek = {"Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday","Thursday","Friday", "Saturday","Sunday"};
        //pass the array to the eStatistics method so they check frequency of e
        eStatistics(daysOfWeek);
    }


    public static int[] eStatistics(String[] names){
        //create new array that will be the same size of the previous array but will have integers
        int[] newArray = new int[names.length];
        //go over each word (element) in the old array
        for(String word : names){
            System.out.println(word);
            //create a counter to store number of e's
            int counter = 0; //counter here so it resets every time we go over a different word
            int lengthOfWord = word.length();
            //go over each letter in the word
            for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfWord ; i++){
                if (word.charAt(i) == 'e'){ //if the letter is an 'e'
                    counter ++; //increment counter by 1
                }
            }
            // we should add the counter to the new array after we end counting the letter e in each word
            // how?
            // newArray[i] = counter;   ????
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        return newArray;
    }
}
```

The purpose of this program is to count the frequency of `'e'` in every word in the array `daysOfWeek` and return an array `{0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}`. But how can I add the total of e's to the new array every time I finish counting how many there are in each word?

Comment: It can be done using other incremental variable, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470874/adding-one-to-each-element-in-an-array-using-an-enhanced-for-loop-in-java/43471260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using java-8, change the method to :

```
public static int[] eStatistics(String[] names) {
    int[] newArray = new int[names.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = (int) names[i].chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'e').count();
    }

    return newArray;
}
```

Here we check the number of times each *String* has the character `e` and store the count at the corresponding index of the array.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I changed (int)daysOfweek for (int)names

Answer (score 0):

Use a traditional *for* loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   ....
   int lengthOfWord = names[i];
   ....
   newArray[i] = counter;    
}
```

If you use the loop variable `i` in your inner loop, change that to `j` or use `j` for the above.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize the [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) API and collect the result to an array, rather than use a traditional for loop:

```
public static int[] eStatistics(String[] names) {
    Function<String, Integer> countEs = string -> string.length() - string.replace("e", "").length();
    return Arrays.stream(names).map(countEs).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
}
```

To explain what this does:

- The first line defines a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) which takes a `String` and returns an `Integer`. This function Counts the number of e's in the string. This function is taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910767/1421925) and may be replaced by any other implementation doing the same thing.

The second line does the actual work:

- `Arrays.stream()` simply creates a `Stream` from the array.
- `map()` converts the `String` to an `Integer` using the function from the first line.
- `mapToInt()` converts each `Integer` to an `int`. This is needed if you want to return an `int[]` and not a `Integer[]`.
- `toArray()` finally collect the `Stream` into an array.